# Запрос на обновление данных в таблице

Tags: sql-server, запрос

У меня в процедуре есть такая вот переменная:

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE (ItemId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                      OldItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Я ее заполнил данными:

```
INSERT @Items (ItemId, OldItemId)
SELECT NEWID(), t1.ItemId
FROM UsersItems t1
WHERE t1.IsActual = 1
```

Также у меня имеется таблица **ItemsToUsers**, которая содержит следующие данные:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemsToUsers
(
  ItemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ItemsToUsers PRIMARY KEY(ItemId, UserId)
)
```

Мне необходимо заменить все *ItemId* в таблице **ItemsToUsers** на *ItemId* из **@Items**, где **ItemsToUsers**.*ItemId* = **@Items**.*OldItemId*.

Не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Делаю так, но это не правильно:

```
UPDATE ItemsToUsers
SET ItemId = @Items.ItemId
WHERE ItemId = @Items.OldItemId
```

Понимаю что нужно сделать условие, что-то на подобии:

```
UPDATE ItemsToUsers
SET ItemId = (SELECT t2.ItemId
              FROM ItemsToUsers t1
                JOIN @Items t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.OldItemId)
WHERE ItemId = @Items.OldItemId
```

Как правильно его составить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш последний вариант содержит практически всё что нужно, требуется лишь небольшая поправка:

```
UPDATE t1
SET ItemId = t2.ItemId
FROM ItemsToUsers t1
    JOIN @Items t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.OldItemId
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно) Все оказалось нанмого проще чем я думал)